# hr line in jumbotron at the end

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image: hr-line]

I got 2 hr lines in my jumbotron. The first one aligns correctly as I want at the beginning of the page. The one at the bottom of the logo should be at the end of the page. I set a vh hight of 100.

```
.jumbotron{
height: 100vh;
```

How can I align the hr at the end? I tried something like align-items-end, but this didn't work out.

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and the html looks like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <!-- Wichtige Meta Daten -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- CSS
  ============================================================================================= -->

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Spectral" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Simple Line Icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simple-line-icons/2.4.1/css/simple-line-icons.css">
    <!-- Custom -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <header class="hero-bg">
    <!-- Start Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top">
        <div class="container m-auto nav-line">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-toggle" aria-controls="navbar-toggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center text-uppercase font-alt" id="navbar-toggle">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mt-1">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#texting" class="nav-link">Texting</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#eventkonzeption" class="nav-link">Event Konzeption</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#impression" class="nav-link">Impressionen</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#ueber" class="nav-link">Über mich</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#kontakt" class="nav-link">Kontakt</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- navbar-nav -->
            </div>
            <!-- navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- container -->
    </nav>
    <!-- Ende Navigation -->
</header>

<!-- Header -->
<section id="home" class="hero-bg jumbotron">
    <div class="container pt-0 pb-5 header-h">
       <hr style="background: white; justify-content-start">
        <div class="align-items-start row justify-content-center">

            <div class="img-logo col align-self-start">
                <img class="img-fluid d-block img-responsive" src="resources/img/logo.png" alt="Rollywood-Logo" >
            </div>
            <!-- col -->
        </div>

        <!-- row -->
           <hr class="align-self-end" style="background: white;"> 

    </div>

    <!-- container -->
</section>
<!-- Header -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Popper -->
    <script src="assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom -->
    <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: try with my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this (while keeping the `<hr>` elements inside the jumbotron), add the classes `d-flex flex-column h-100` to the container inside the jumbotron and then add the `mt-auto` class (margin-top:auto) and optionally the `mb-0` class (margin-bottom:0) to the last `<hr>` element.

`d-flex flex-column` classes enable a flexbox column and `h-100` gives it 100% height. `mt-auto` on the `<hr>` then pushes it down. Via the `pb-*` class on the container, you can then control how far from the bottom the `<hr>` sits. In this case, I've chosen `pb-4`.

Click "run code snippet" below and expand to full page for testing:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<header class="hero-bg">
    <!-- Start Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top">
        <div class="container m-auto nav-line">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-toggle" aria-controls="navbar-toggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center text-uppercase font-alt" id="navbar-toggle">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mt-1">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#texting" class="nav-link">Texting</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#eventkonzeption" class="nav-link">Event Konzeption</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#impression" class="nav-link">Impressionen</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#ueber" class="nav-link">Über mich</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#kontakt" class="nav-link">Kontakt</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- navbar-nav -->
            </div>
            <!-- navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- container -->
    </nav>
    <!-- Ende Navigation -->
</header>

<!-- Header -->
<section id="home" class="hero-bg jumbotron bg-info pb-0" style="height: 100vh;">
    <div class="container d-flex flex-column h-100 pt-0 pb-4 header-h">
        <hr style="background: white; height: 1px; width: 100%; border: 0">
        <div class="align-items-start row justify-content-center mx-auto">

            <div class="img-logo col align-self-start">
                <img class="img-fluid d-block img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/500x100" alt="Rollywood-Logo" >
            </div>
            <!-- col -->
        </div>

        <!-- row -->
        <hr class="mt-auto mb-0" style="background: white; height: 1px; width: 100%; border: 0">

    </div>

    <!-- container -->
</section>
<!-- Header -->
```

Note: I've also added `mx-auto` to the logo image div to center it horizontally.

Comment: Cheers, I'll try that tomorrow :)

Answer (score 1):

Every thing is fine with your code, Except you have coded `<hr>` tags inside the jumbotron, just add those `hr` tags before and after the jumbotron, then you will get result as u expected

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <!-- Wichtige Meta Daten -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- CSS
  ============================================================================================= -->

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Spectral" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Simple Line Icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simple-line-icons/2.4.1/css/simple-line-icons.css">
    <!-- Custom -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
 <style>
 .jumbotron{
height: 100vh;}
 </style>
</head>

<body>

    <header class="hero-bg">
    <!-- Start Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top">
        <div class="container m-auto nav-line">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-toggle" aria-controls="navbar-toggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center text-uppercase font-alt" id="navbar-toggle">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mt-1">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#texting" class="nav-link">Texting</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#eventkonzeption" class="nav-link">Event Konzeption</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#impression" class="nav-link">Impressionen</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#ueber" class="nav-link">Über mich</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#kontakt" class="nav-link">Kontakt</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- navbar-nav -->
            </div>
            <!-- navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- container -->
    </nav>
    <!-- Ende Navigation -->
</header>

<!-- Header -->
       <hr style="background: white; justify-content-start"/>
<section id="home" class="hero-bg jumbotron">
    <div class="container pt-0 pb-5 header-h">
        <div class="align-items-start row justify-content-center">

            <div class="img-logo col align-self-start">
                <img class="img-fluid d-block img-responsive" src="resources/img/logo.png" alt="Rollywood-Logo" >
            </div>
            <!-- col -->
        </div>

        <!-- row -->

    </div>

    <!-- container -->
</section>
           <hr class="align-self-end" style="background: white;"/> 
<!-- Header -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Popper -->
    <script src="assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom -->
    <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```